# redirect olddomain.com/folder/AmazonASIN.html to newdomain.com/AmazonASIN.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

this is very important question for me,

How to permanent redirect this url :

`http://olddomain.com/folder/AmazonASIN.html to http://newdomain.com/AmazonASIN.html`

any one there can answer this question.
thank before.

regard,

Comment: So if anyone views that web page it redirects to the new one?

Comment: anyone can suggest me how to do this? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If they're served under the same vhost (meaning you've parked the old domain at the new):

Add this to `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} olddomain.com$
RewriteRule [^/]+/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If their separately host (different servers or different vhosts) add this to the old domain's `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [^/]+/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Specifically for that file only this would be the line:

```
RewriteRule [^/]+/(AmazonASIN\.html) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```